# Ad Hoc Network Connection causes Blue Screen of Death DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Tags: networking, windows-8, bsod, ad-hoc-network, upnp

I recently had my home internet go down, so I stood up a tethered Ad Hoc Wireless hotspot from my 4G mobile phone. However, once I connected my Windows 8.1 64 bit computer to it, it blue screened with DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION.

I then rebooted, and noted that whenever I connected to the Ad Hoc network, my 'System Interrupts' process would go crazy, up to ~15% (maxing out a thread) until it bluescreened. The DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION was about the overutilization of System Interrupts in the minidump files.

If I then disconnected from it, the utilization whet back down, no bluescreen. I then traced what was making connections and it's 'svchost.exe' making an immediate connection to 239.255.255.250.

While this isn't a valid Internet I.P. address, it is the reserved IPv4 address for the Simple Service Discovery Protocol for uPnP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol

Why would connecting to an Ad Hoc network blow up my system interrupts until I got the BSOD repeatedly? How would I go about fixing it, or see what dll svchost.exe has loaded? Help!?!?!

Comment: upload the dmp file.

Comment: To what? Superuser allows you to attach .dmp files?

Comment: to dropbox, OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A9286A7E77087BD!899&authkey=!ADUwgzQIoGgQGi0&ithint=file%2c.dmp

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel WIFI driver `NETwNs64.sys` seams to cause the crash.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period.
Arg3: 0000000000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFF8017A960FB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8017abdffa3 to fffff8017aa60440

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!KeUpdateRunTime
hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl
NETwNs64!mmacTxUtilPostDropPacketEvent
NETwNs64!mtxHandlePacketArrayEvent
NETwNs64!cfPumpTheEventQueue
NETwNs64!fpStartFlowWithEvent
NETwNs64!mmacAlMpSendPackets
NETwNs64!hmacAlPtSendPackets
NETwNs64!htxHandleTxMgmtFrame
NETwNs64!cfPumpTheEventQueue
NETwNs64!emDelayedEventRoutine
ndis!ndisMTimerObjectDpc
nt!KiExecuteAllDpcs
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KxRetireDpcList
nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue

IMAGE_NAME:  NETwNs64.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_isr_netwns64!mmactxutilpostdroppacketevent

    Loaded symbol image file: NETwNs64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\NETwNs64.sys
    Image name: NETwNs64.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Oct 06 16:45:03 2011 (4E8DBEEF)
```

[Update the driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=Intel%20Wifi), yours is from 2011.

Comment: Thanks! What did you use to obtain that from the .dmp file? WinDbg?

Comment: yes, I used WinDbg.

Comment: What did you set for your "Symbol File Path"? I used `SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` as mentioned at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-use-windbg-debugger-to-troubleshoot-a-blue-screen-of-death/#. and I can't get that information since it can't find the symbols for NETwNs64.sys

Comment: your NETwNs64.sys is the inbox driver and I got the PDB from the Symbol offline installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028